# @Required annotation on subclass implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a situation where I'd like to annotate a setter method as `@Required` on only some of the implementations of my `parentClass`.  However, unless I annotate the base class Spring does not identify the method as being required in the config (that is, if the field is absent I get no "Required property missing: foo".  Below is the code I'm trying to use:

```
public abstract class parentClass {
  public abstract void setFoo(Object foo);
}

public abstract class childClass extends parentClass {
  @Override
  @Required 
  public void setFoo(Object foo) {
    //setter code
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Is it possible to specify an annotation only for certain child classes?

Answer (score 2):

Annotations on items other than classes are not inherited. See the [@Inherited Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html)

> Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated type is used to annotate anything other than a class. Note also that this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.

I'm not sure how JSR 305 processors manage this trick.

Comment: So basically you can't add annotations to overridden abstract methods except in the root abstract class/interface?

Comment: Now, I'm not sure.  The `@Inherited` Javadoc quote is about the other direction. It says that adding `@Required` to the parent class does nothing to the child class. Perhaps someone else can help.